# Defaulting Optional orElse with Optional.empty in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Java 8 here. I need to search two lists of POJOs for a string and want to use the Stream/Optional APIs correctly.

If the name appears in the first list ("`lunches`") then I want to return an optional containing it. Else, if the name appears in the second list ("`dinners`") then I want to return an optional containing it. Otherwise I want to return `Optional.empty()` if the name doesn't existing in either list. My best attempt thus far:

```java
public class Restaurant {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<Food> lunches;
    private List<Food> dinners;

    public Optional<Food> findFoodByName(String name) {

        return Optional.of(lunches.stream()
                                  .filter(food -> food.getName()
                                                      .equalsIgnoreCase(name))
                                  .findFirst())
                       .orElse(dinners.stream()
                                      .filter(food -> food.getName()
                                                          .equalsIgnoreCase(name))
                       .findFirst());
//                     .orElse(null);        TODO: how to return empty optional if neither in 'lunches' nor 'dinners'?

    }

}
```

**Can anyone help me cross the finish line here?**

Comment: Hi @Deadpool, can you elaborate? `orElse(null)` is commented out already...are you saying my code will work as-is? Meaning that if the name isn't found in `dinners` the method will somehow magically return `Optional.empty()`?!?!

Comment: If only you were using Java 9+, this would be the perfect use case for [`Optional#or(Supplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#or(java.util.function.Supplier)). Though Deadpool's solution may still be better.

Comment: is order important to you. You have to search first in lunches then in dinners ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Combine both the list using `Stream.of` and check for element or return `Optional.empty()`

```
Stream.of(lunches, dinners)
      .flatMap(List::stream)
      .filter(s -> s.getName()
                    .equalsIgnoreCase(name))
      .findFirst();
```

As per the suggestion from @Holger you can also use `Stream.concat` to concat two streams and then check for element

```
Stream.concat(lunches.stream(), dinners.stream())
      .filter(s -> s.getName()
                    .equalsIgnoreCase(name))
      .findFirst();
```

Comment: For two streams, you may use `Stream.concat(lunches.stream(), dinners.stream())` instead of `Stream.of(lunches, dinners).flatMap(List::stream)`

Answer (score 4):

You can do like this too:

```
 Optional<Food> firstTry = lunches.stream()
                                  .filter(f -> f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name))
                                  .findFirst();
 return firstTry.map(Optional::of)
                .orElse(dinners.stream()
                        .filter(f -> f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)).findFirst());
```

Or in Java9

```
firstTry.or(() -> dinners.stream().filter(s -> s.equalsIgnoreCase(name)).findFirst());
```

---

As @Slaw commented correctly use of `orElseGet()` avoid eagerly computing.

```
Optional<Food> firstTry = lunches.stream().filter(...)...findFirst();
Supplier<Optional<Food>> secondTry = () -> dinners.stream()...findFirst();
```

and at the end

```
return firstTry.map(Optional::of).orElseGet(secondTry);
```

Comment: You might want to use `orElseGet` to avoid eagerly computing the "else value".

Comment: Thanks @HadiJ (+1) however what happens if the `name` is not found in either `firstTry` or `secondTry`?

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup It will return `Optional.empty()`